# What is a succinct way to draw these boxes with arrows?

Tags: diagrams, plain-tex

I would like to recreate diagrams of this form (from Iverson's A Programming Language book). The math inside the boxes is easy, but I'd like to be able to programmatically create those boxes and labeled arrows. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

I'd prefer to use plaintex but I'm willing to delve into the more complex world of LaTeX if it will make this work easier.

Comment: You can use TikZ also with plain TeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=10mm,label=\theenumi]
\item \tikzmark{a}$z \leftarrow c$
\item $p \leftarrow \in(v(z))$
\item \tikzmark{b}$v(f) : 2$
\item $i \leftarrow 1$
\item $x \leftarrow \in(0)$
\item \tikzmark{c}$j \leftarrow (\theta/f)_i$
\item $x \leftarrow x \oplus (((p \overset{\scriptscriptstyle +}{\times} a^{j-1}) \downarrow a^{p_j})/z)$ 
\item $i \leftarrow i + 1$
\item \tikzmark{d}$i : v(f)$
\item $z \leftarrow (\circ) \oplus x$
\item $p \leftarrow (\theta/f) \int p$
\item $p \leftarrow (1 + (p \overset{\scriptscriptstyle +}{\times} a^2 )) \oplus \overline{a}^2 / p$
\item $f \leftarrow (\theta/f) \int f$
\item \tikzmark{e}$f \leftarrow (+/a^2/f) \oplus \overline{a}^2 / f$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]\footnotesize
 \draw ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=4mm]pic cs:a) rectangle ([xshift=50mm,yshift=-3mm]pic cs:e);
 \draw[->] ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:a) -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:a);
 \draw[->] ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:d) -- node [above] {$\leq$} ([xshift=-6mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:d) -- ([xshift=-6mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:c) -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:c);
 \draw[->] ([xshift=50mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:b) -- node [above] {$=$} ([xshift=56mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:b);
 \draw[->] ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:e) -- ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:e) -- ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:b) -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=.5ex]pic cs:b);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Not the best solution, since the items are not equally distributed possibly due to the `\overset` macro